# Match Items In Multi-Level Embedded Arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use the following collection which represents sports > categories > tournaments.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597846358bbbc4440895f2e8"),
    "Name" : [ 
        { "k" : "en-US", "v" : "Soccer" }, 
        { "k" : "fr-FR", "v" : "Football" }
    ],
    "Categories" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                { "k" : "en-US", "v" : "France" }, 
                { "k" : "fr-FR", "v" : "France" }
            ],
            "Tournaments" : [ 
                {
                    "Name" : [ 
                        { "k" : "en-US", "v" : "Ligue 1" }, 
                        { "k" : "fr-FR", "v" : "Ligue 1" }
                    ],
                }, 
                {
                    "Name" : [ 
                        { "k" : "en-US", "v" : "Ligue 2" }, 
                        { "k" : "fr-FR", "v" : "Ligue 2" }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                { "k" : "en-US", "v" : "England" }, 
                { "k" : "fr-FR", "v" : "Angleterre" }
            ],
            "Tournaments" : [ 
                {
                    "Name" : [ 
                        { "k" : "en-US", "v" : "Premier League" }, 
                        { "k" : "fr-FR", "v" : "Premier League" }
                    ],
                }, 
                {
                    "Name" : [ 
                        { "k" : "en-US", "v" : "Championship" }, 
                        { "k" : "fr-FR", "v" : "Championnat" }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I want to query the collection using the category’s name and the tournament’s name. I’ve successfully use “$elemMatch” with the following code:

```
db.getCollection('Sport').find({
    Categories: {
        $elemMatch: {
            Name: {
                $elemMatch: { v: "France" }
            },
            Tournaments: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    Name: {
                        $elemMatch: { v: "Ligue 1" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { "Categories.$": 1, Name: 1 })
```

However, I cannot receive only the matching tournament in the category object.
Using the answer in this question: [MongoDB Projection of Nested Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982285/mongodb-projection-of-nested-arrays), I’ve built an aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('Sport').aggregate([{
            "$match": {
                "Categories": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "Name": {
                            "$elemMatch": {
                                "v": "France"
                            }
                        },
                        "Tournaments": {
                            "$elemMatch": {
                                "Name": {
                                    "$elemMatch": {
                                        "v": "Ligue 1"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$addFields": {
                "Categories": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": {
                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$Categories",
                                "as": "category",
                                "in": {
                                    "Tournaments": {
                                        "$filter": {
                                            "input": "$$category.Tournaments",
                                            "as": "tournament",
                                            "cond": {
                                                // stuck here
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "as": "category",
                        "cond": {
                            // stuck here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

I tried to use a condition but MongoDB doesn’t recognize (*Use of undefined variable:*) $$KEEP and $$PRUNE ([$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)) when I use $anyElementTrue then $map on the “Name” property.

**My question:** how can I check that the collection of names contains my string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm more surprised that on the answer you reference I did not not "strongly recommend you do not nest arrays" like this. Nesting in this way is impossible to update atomically until the next release of MongoDB, and they are notoriously difficult to query.

For this particular case you would do:

```
db.getCollection('Sport').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "Categories": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "Name.v": "France",
        "Tournaments.Name.v": "Ligue 1"    
      }
    }    
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "Categories": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$Categories",
            "as": "c",
            "in": {
              "Name": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$c.Name",
                  "as": "n",
                  "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$n.v", "France" ] }
                }    
              },
              "Tournaments": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": "$$c.Tournaments",
                      "as": "t",
                      "in": {
                        "Name": {
                          "$filter": {
                            "input": "$$t.Name",
                            "as": "n",
                            "cond": { 
                              "$eq": [ "$$n.v", "Ligue 1" ]
                            }
                          }
                        }        
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "as": "t",
                  "cond": {
                    "$ne": [{ "$size": "$$t.Name" }, 0]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "c",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            { "$ne": [{ "$size": "$$c.Name" },0] },
            { "$ne": [{ "$size": "$$c.Tournaments" },0] }
          ]
        }
      } 
    }  
  }}
])
```

Which returns the result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597846358bbbc4440895f2e8"),
    "Name" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "en-US",
            "v" : "Soccer"
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "fr-FR",
            "v" : "Football"
        }
    ],
    "Categories" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : [ 
                {
                    "k" : "en-US",
                    "v" : "France"
                }, 
                {
                    "k" : "fr-FR",
                    "v" : "France"
                }
            ],
            "Tournaments" : [ 
                {
                    "Name" : [ 
                        {
                            "k" : "en-US",
                            "v" : "Ligue 1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "k" : "fr-FR",
                            "v" : "Ligue 1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The whole point is that each array needs a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), and at the outer levels you are looking for [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) not being `0` as a result of "inner" [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operations on contained arrays.

Since the "inner" arrays can change in content as a result, the "outer" arrays need a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to return the "changed" elements.

So in terms of the structure `"Categories"` needs a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) because it has inner elements. And the "inner" `"Tournaments"` needs a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) for the same reason. Every array all the way to the final properties need [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), and each wrapping array with a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) has a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with a [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) condition.

That's the general logic pattern, and it works by repeating that pattern for each nested level. As stated though, it's pretty horrible. Which is why you really should avoid "nesting" like this at all costs. The increased complexity just about always outweighs any perceived gains.

> I should also note you went a little overboard with [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), You really only need it at the `"Categories"` array level since that's the only thing that has multiple conditions to be met for it's element.
>
> The sub-elements can use plain ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) since they are only "singular" conditions within their respective arrays. So that does cut down on the terse syntax somewhat and still matches exactly the same documents.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use nested array because in my design, those embedded documents will never be queried without their parent sport. We tried to avoid the relational design based on one collection per type. However, you’re right, I only tried to update root level array (with success) but it seems impossible to update nested array without replacing the entire object.