# MongoDB projection of an array nested within an array

Tags: mongodb

*(Note: although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982285/mongodb-projection-of-nested-arrays) has a similar title, it actually deals more with filtering than with projection; I wasn't able to understand how it may apply to my usecase.

If it is relevant, then I apologise in advance :) )*

Given the following document structure:

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "groups" : [
        {
            "name" : "group1.1",
            "contacts" : [
                { "localId" : "c1.1", "address" : "some address 1" },
                { "localId" : "c1.2", "address" : "some address 2" },
                { "localId" : "c1.3", "address" : "some address 3" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "group1.2",
            "contacts" : [
                { "localId" : "c1.1", "address" : "some address 1" },
                { "localId" : "c1.4", "address" : "some address 3" }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id" : "2",
    "groups" : [
        {
            "name" : "group2.1",
            "contacts" : [
                { "localId" : "c2.1", "address" : "some address 1" },
                { "localId" : "c2.2", "address" : "some address 2" },
                { "localId" : "c2.3", "address" : "some address 3" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "group2.2",
            "contacts" : [
                { "localId" : "c2.1", "address" : "some address 1" },
                { "localId" : "c2.3", "address" : "some address 3" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I create a projection to return *only* the `contacts` arrays within the `groups` arrays, and *all* elements within these arrays?
I still want to maintain the original structure (i.e arrays should not be flattened)

i.e required output would be:

```
{
    "groups" : [
      {
        "contacts" : [
          { "localId" : "c1.1", "address" : "some address 1" },
          { "localId" : "c1.2", "address" : "some address 2" },
          { "localId" : "c1.3", "address" : "some address 3" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "contacts" : [
          { "localId" : "c1.1", "address" : "some address 1" },
          { "localId" : "c1.4", "address" : "some address 3" }
        ]
      }
    ]
},
{
    "groups" : [
      {
        "contacts" : [
          { "localId" : "c2.1", "address" : "some address 1" },
          { "localId" : "c2.2", "address" : "some address 2" },
          { "localId" : "c2.3", "address" : "some address 3" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "contacts" : [
          { "localId" : "c2.1", "address" : "some address 1" },
          { "localId" : "c2.3", "address" : "some address 3" }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

for a non-array property, something like `{'groups.name': 1}` works as expected.

I've tried something like `db.collection.findOne({}, { 'groups.contacts': 1 })` to try and get the contacts as well, but this did not return a `contacts` field at all..

Comment: It gives me expected result `db.collection.findOne({}, { 'groups.contacts': 1 })`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/0AnbiLI6US- ??

Comment: Same as @AnthonyWinzlet here, i get what is expected(which is what u ask for)

Comment: yup, came back this morning and was working ok. don't know what happened there... thanks both!

Comment: Please close the question if you made a mistake.

Comment: Sorry I missed the 'close' button.. done now